# recyclerview notifyItemInserted notifyItemRemoved random behaviour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been stuck for hours on this. I have an activity with a recyclerview in. To add to the list, the user goes to another activity, where he selects from a list of strings. The second activity returns the string to the first activity, and the string is added to the end of the recyclerview.

If the user clicks a long click on the item in the recyclerview, a dialog comes up, where he can delete the item. However once an item is deleted, things go terribly wrong. Sometimes the list changes, sometimes when you add another item from the second activity, the old item comes back. Its so random, its hard to explain exactly. In the logs I see that the correct string has come back from the second activity, but the recycler view doesn't display it properly. Whats going wrong?

Even when the list is "messed up", when i reenter the activity, I call the list form my SharedPreferences and it all appears ok. So the ArrayList is correct, just its not displaying correctly in the recyclerview once somethings been deleted. I hope its clear.

Here is my code in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_off_limits);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    offLimitsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

    offLimitsItemsList = SharedPreferencesManager.getOffLimitsItemsList(this);


    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Off limits (This week)");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


    offLimitsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.off_limits_recycler_view);
    offLimitsAdapter = new OffLimitsAdapter(offLimitsItemsList);


    offLimitsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OffLimitsAdapter.ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(final int position, View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick pos = " + position);


            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(OffLimitsActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_delete)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                            Log.d(TAG, offLimitsItemsList.get(position) + " removed");

                            offLimitsItemsList.remove(position);

                            offLimitsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

                            SharedPreferencesManager.setOffLimitsItemsList(OffLimitsActivity.this, offLimitsItemsList);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
            builder.create();
            builder.show();

        }

    });


    offLimitsRecyclerView.setAdapter(offLimitsAdapter);
    offLimitsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");
        String itemEaten= data.getStringExtra(OFF_LIMITS_ITEM_EATEN);
        offLimitsItemsList.add(itemEaten);
        Log.d(TAG, "Item eaten: " + itemEaten);

        offLimitsAdapter.notifyItemInserted(offLimitsItemsList.size()-1);

        SharedPreferencesManager.setOffLimitsItemsList(OffLimitsActivity.this, offLimitsItemsList);

    }


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.off_limits_menu_add_item, menu);


    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add_off_limits:

            Log.d(TAG, "Add clicked");

            Intent intent = new Intent(OffLimitsActivity.this, SearchOffLimitsItemActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SEARCH_OFF_LIMIT_RESULT_CODE);

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

And here is the adapter:

```
public class OffLimitsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


private static ClickListener clickListener;

public TextView offLimitsTextViewItem;
ArrayList<String> offLimitsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

public OffLimitsAdapter(ArrayList<String> offLimitsItemsList) {

    this.offLimitsItemsList = offLimitsItemsList;

}


public interface ClickListener {

    void onItemLongClick(int position, View v);
}


class OffLimitsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener{

    public OffLimitsViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        view.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        offLimitsTextViewItem = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.off_limits_item_text_view);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemLongClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        return false;
    }


}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    OffLimitsAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return offLimitsItemsList.size();
}

@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.off_limts_item_row, parent, false);




        return new OffLimitsViewHolder(itemView);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


                offLimitsTextViewItem.setText("" + holder.getAdapterPosition() + ". " + offLimitsItemsList.get(position));

        }
    }
```

Comment: have you tried calling `offLimitsAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());` after  `offLimitsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);` ?

Comment: Yes. have tried. Thanks

Comment: was it working for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Altough this might not be the solution you should go for, but does it work if you use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of `.notifyItemXXX()`?

Comment: Tried this many times, doesn't work